# First post review for deleted user

Tags: discussion, review

In going through the first post queue, I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/743156) which was posted by a now-deleted user.  It would seem to me that most of the reasoning behind the queue is to help out and provide feedback to a brand new user, which can't happen if that user no longer has an account on the site.

Comment: I got the same exact post in when I was reviewing and wasn't sure what to do with it, so thanks for asking this question

Answer (score 4):

The primary purpose of the First Posts queue is the same as with the other queues, to review content. Providing feedback to a brand new user is important, but you can still review the answer even if the answerer's account is no more:

1. Upvote it if you feel is useful,
2. Downvote it if you feel it isn't,
3. Comment on it, if you have something useful to add.

I realize that #3 might sound strange, but your comment will be read by everyone who happens upon the answer, not just the OP, if you have something useful to say, say it.

Comment: I realize it's still *possible* to provide feedback to people other than the OP, but it does seem that providing feedback to the OP is of higher priority to that queue.  Votes on the post are actually quite valuable to them, but without the account they are unlikely to see it.  If the post is simply of low quality and needs improvement it is likely to also be in the low quality queue (which should be fine even for a post by a deleted user).

Comment: @Servy New users are typically unaware of our (many) little rules and guidelines, which is why a "First Posts" queue makes sense, and providing feedback to them _is_ important, just not more important that reviewing the actual content. I think this is an edge case, don't know why that user decided to delete their account, but it's incredibly rare to find a first post from a deleted account. Still, rare or not, since you can still review the content...